# Using drools expert with dynamic decision tables

Tags: drools, rule-engine

Here's what I had like to do.

I had like to put "rules" in a database table. This is sort of like the drools xls decision table format  except that all the rules will be rows in a table. This way I can modify the rules easily . I need to put this in a table and not an xls because my rules could be frequently changing. Is this possible with drools? Can I build a knowledgebase with rules  retrieved from a DB (instead of a DRL or a xls file) and every time rules change can I rebuild the knowledge base from scratch (or maybe just parts of the knowledgebase, essentially update only those rules that's changed..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what kind of rules you have in mind. A database-backed approach makes sense if you have lots of rules that have the same structure, and which only vary according to certain 'parameters'. In this case you can write a single generic rule, and use the database to store all of the combinations that apply. For example, suppose you have a rules to calculate shipping rates per country, for an order, e.g.

```
rule "Shipping rates to France"
when
    $order : Order(country == 'fr')
then
    $order.setShippingRate(10.0);
    update(order);
end

// Similar rules for other countries…
```

You could replace these rules data from your database where each `CountryShippingRate` specifies the rate for one country. Then you insert all of the `CountryShippingRate` rows as fact objects in the rule session, and a single rule, like:

```
rule "Shipping rates"
when
    $order : Order($country : country)
    CountryShippingRate($rate : rate, country == $country)
then
    $order.setShippingRate($rate);
    update(order);
end
```

In practice, it turns out that lots of decision table type rules can be rewritten this way.

Comment: @Peter Hilton Please look on this question. Thanks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322576/stop-rules-on-update-facts-drools